# Python loop not looping through xrange

Tags: python, numpy

One part of my program requires that I check to make sure two "things" don't overlap (occupy the same space, i.e., coordinates). For some reason it doesn't loop through the entire xranges. I am **sure** that it is a simple programming mistake, but I've reduced to program to a simple MWE and the problem persists!

```
import numpy as np

class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, yx):
        self.yx = yx

def overlap(fooFun):
    n = len(fooFun)
    for i in xrange(n):
        for j in xrange(n):
            if i != j: # Don't check itself
                print '----------------------'
                print 'i,j:', i, j
                print 'Comparing:', fooFun[i].yx, fooFun[j].yx
                if np.array_equal(fooFun[i].yx, fooFun[j].yx) == True:
                    print 'Overlap!'
                    return False
                else:
                    print 'No Overlap!'
                    return True

# Test functions/class
yx = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 0]])
n = len(yx)

fooGroup = []
for i in xrange(n):
    fooGroup.append(foo(yx[i]))

overlap(fooGroup)
```

Which results in:

```
----------------------
i,j: 0 1
Comparing: [0 0] [0 1]
No Overlap!
```

For **some** reason this does not loop through i = 0, 1, 2 and j = 0, 1, 2.

Comment: @askewchan: I usually do program that way, but I was trying to eliminate any uncertainty in the code. I had been working on this problem for almost the entire day, and didn't want to miss something trivial (although I still managed to...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `return` statement causes the function to end right away. It skips everything. If you want to run through all the loops, you need to remove your `return` statements.

Comment: Only the second `return` is problematic. The first one is in the right place.

Comment: Or remove the one in the condition that the loops should continue on.

Comment: Well, as embarrassing as that is, I am glad it works now. I created a flag called move, which is given the value true or false instead. Seems to work just great.